# Defined case returns "unknown column" when called [MySQL]

Tags: mysql

I'm making a defined case for the location of a product, and then want to return that case later as a value. However, I get the error "Unknown column location in 'field list'."

```
SELECT location, avg(pcnt), max(pcnt), min(pcnt)
  FROM (
    -- create temporary table 'a' to serve data from inner typing table created below
    SELECT a.date_key, a.num_snowflakes/k.tot_snowflakes AS pcnt
      FROM (
        SELECT 
          date_key,
          CASE
            WHEN location_type_key=2 then 'at_customer' 
            WHEN location_type_key IN (1,13) then 'on_floor' 
            WHEN location_type_key IN (6,7,11) then 'sat1'
            WHEN location_type_key IN (4,5) then 'film'
            WHEN location_type_key IN (8,9) then 'repair'
            WHEN location_type_key IN (12) then 'inspection'
            WHEN location_type_key IN (2) then 'outside' 
            ELSE NULL END AS location,
          COUNT(distinct garment_key) AS num_snowflakes, 
          COUNT(distinct product_key) AS num_skus

          FROM database
          -- excluding vendor return and retired
            WHERE location_type_key NOT IN (3,10)
            -- between 6/15/13 and 8/15/13
              AND date_key >= 20130615 AND date_key <= 20130815
          -- aggregates by day and location case    
          GROUP BY date_key, location
        ) AS a
        JOIN 
        -- create temporary table 'k' to serve 'tot_snowflakes' to table 'a' above
          (SELECT b.date_key, sum(b.num_snowflakes) AS tot_snowflakes 
              FROM (
                SELECT 
                  date_key, 
                  CASE   
                    WHEN location_type_key=2 then 'at_customer' 
                    WHEN location_type_key IN (1,13) then 'on_floor' 
                    WHEN location_type_key IN (6,7,11) then 'sat1'
                    WHEN location_type_key IN (4,5) then 'film'
                    WHEN location_type_key IN (8,9) then 'repair'
                    WHEN location_type_key IN (12) then 'inspection'
                    WHEN location_type_key IN (2) then 'outside' 
                    ELSE NULL END AS location,
                  COUNT(distinct garment_key) AS num_snowflakes, 
                  COUNT(distinct product_key) AS num_skus

                  FROM database
                    WHERE location_type_key NOT IN (3,10)
                    -- between 6/15/13 and 8/15/13
                      AND date_key >= 20130615 AND date_key <= 20130815
                  -- aggregates by day and location case    
                  GROUP BY date_key, location
                ) AS b
            ) AS k
          ON a.date_key=k.date_key
      GROUP BY a.date_key, a.location
    ) AS z
```

I've tried to make sure I'm always calling the right table, so I'm not sure where the error is coming from. Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: `database`? very descriptive name.. /irony.

Comment: The query is quite huge, but I don't see a `location` in one of the fields of the two joined selects. You should remove the outer select to check if the join really has a field `location`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, I took out the real database name  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outermost query SELECTs FROM table z.

Table z is derived from SELECT FROM table a JOIN table k.

Table a is derived from SELECT FROM table "database".

Table k is derived from SELECT FROM derived table b.

Table b is derived from SELECT FROM base table "database".

The short answer here is that the first line of your query is in actually asking for this:

```
SELECT z.location, avg(z.pcnt), max(z.pcnt), min(z.pcnt)
```

Derived table z only has two columns, "date_key" and "pcnt".

```
(SELECT a.date_key, a.num_snowflakes/k.tot_snowflakes AS pcnt
...
) AS z
```

For the query to work, table z needs a location, which has to be explicit in each of the nested selects until you can trace it down to the base table you intend to actually read it from.

It also seems like the query is otherwise doing more work than necessary for the results you're trying to accomplish, but I've been staring at it until my eyes have lost their ability to focus, so I'll stick with this answer for the moment: each derived table that needs to percolate its "location" column up toward the outermost select needs to explicitly SELECT it.